# Transparent Text With Background Image

Tags: html, css

I would like to create something like this:

```css
header {
  height: 2000px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 10em;
  color: white;
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1104509/pexels-photo-1104509.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=green-leaves-plant-1104509.jpg&fm=jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</header>
```

But I am hoping for better browser support...the -webkit styles don't translate well. Is there another CSS method or are we stuck with javascript?

Comment: [This page](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text/) shows some methods of achieving this using SVG, and there's also a CSS polyfill included there as well!

Comment: Yeah, the only bummer is the SVG stuff would kill SEO. Kinda crazy with things such as CSS Grid coming out that we still can't do this easily!

Answer (score 1):

`background-clip` has pretty good browser support. For anyone searching for alternative css only approaches, following is an example using `mix-blend-mode` but browser support as of the date of this answer is more limited than `background-clip` (so if you run the snippet below on Edge or IE, I am not sure what you will see but you should be able to run OP's snippet in the question on those browsers).

```css
header {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1104509/pexels-photo-1104509.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=green-leaves-plant-1104509.jpg&fm=jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 2000px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 10em;
  height: 2000px;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks! At the very least this property is not exclusive to webkit :)